# Regex.IsMatch vs string.Contains

Tags: .net, regex, string

Is there any difference in speed/memory usage for these two equivalent expressions:

```
Regex.IsMatch(Message, "1000")
```

Vs

```
Message.Contains("1000")
```

Any situations where one is better than other ?

The context of this question is as follows:
I was making some changes to legacy code which contained the Regex expression to find whether a string is contained within another string. Being legacy code I did not make any changes to that and in the code review somebody suggested that Regex.IsMatch should be replaced by string.Contains. So I was wondering whether the change was worth making.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex VS Contains. Best Performance ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023792/regex-vs-contains-best-performance)

Comment: @Random, that's related, but a more complicated example.  It's also using Java, which has a different regex syntax.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For simple cases `String.Contains` will give you better performance but `String.Contains` will not allow you to do complex pattern matching. Use `String.Contains` for non-pattern matching scenarios (like the one in your example) and use regular expressions for scenarios in which you need to do more complex pattern matching.

A regular expression has a certain amount of overhead associated with it (expression parsing, compilation, execution, etc.) that a simple method like `String.Contains` simply does not have which is why `String.Contains` will outperform a regular expression in examples like yours.

Comment: Obviously this is a very old answer, but maybe you could give your sources? @user279470 seems to present some very good evidence that this answer is wrong.

Comment: and then there's this benchmark that agrees with Andrew http://stackoverflow.com/a/17579471/289992 Take your pick!

Answer (score 41):

`String.Contains` is slower when you compare it to a [compiled regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Considerably slower, even!

You can test it running this benchmark:

```
class Program
{
  public static int FoundString;
  public static int FoundRegex;

  static void DoLoop(bool show)
  {
    const string path = "C:\\file.txt";
    const int iterations = 1000000;
    var content = File.ReadAllText(path);

    const string searchString = "this exists in file";
    var searchRegex = new Regex("this exists in file");

    var containsTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
      if (content.Contains(searchString))
      {
        FoundString++;
      }
    }
    containsTimer.Stop();

    var regexTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
      if (searchRegex.IsMatch(content))
      {
        FoundRegex++;
      }
    }
    regexTimer.Stop();

    if (!show) return;

    Console.WriteLine("FoundString: {0}", FoundString);
    Console.WriteLine("FoundRegex: {0}", FoundRegex);
    Console.WriteLine("containsTimer: {0}", containsTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("regexTimer: {0}", regexTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    DoLoop(false);
    DoLoop(true);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Running it on a random EDIFACT INVRP file of 60kb with "this exists in file" stuffed in halfway through:

containsTimer: 84925
regexTimer: 10633

Comment: Though it's not String.Contains(), I just modified a search & replace function in my program to use a compiled Regex object instead of 'Value.ToString.IndexOf(SearchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)'.  My replace-all test using a >44,000 row DataGridView (1,921 replacements) went from ~7.5 minutes to ~30 seconds.

Comment: If you add .IndexOf to this, it's even slower than .Contains. Regex is just awesome.

Comment: content.Contains win. because `new Regex("this exists in file")` != `content.Contains(searchString)`...
but `new Regex(".+this exists in file.+")`.

Comment: yes, when `Contains` finds the search string closer to the start of the string `Contains` wins. Otherwise regex wins, I guess we should say regex has better performence overall but `Contains` wins for  small strings(lets say  below  1000-2000chars)

Answer (score 9):

To determine which is the fastest you will have to benchmark your own system. However, regular expressions are complex and chances are that `String.Contains()` will be the fastest and in your case also the simplest solution.

The implementation of `String.Contains()` will eventually call the native method  `IndexOfString()` and the implementation of that is only known by Microsoft. However, a good algorithm for implementing this method is using what is known as the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). The complexity of this algorithm is *O(m + n)* where *m* is the length of the string you are searching for and *n* is the length of the string you are searching making it a very efficient algorithm.

Actually, the efficiency of search using regular expression can be as low *O(n)* depending on the implementation so it may still be competetive in some situations. Only a benchmark will be able to determine this.

If you are really concerned about search speed Christian Charras and Thierry Lecroq has a lot of material about [exact string matching algorithms](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/) at Université de Rouen.

Answer (score 6):

@user279470 I was looking for an efficient way to count words just for fun and came across [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-count) .  I gave it the OpenOffice Thesaurus dat file to iterate through.  Total Word Count came to 1575423.

Now, my end goal didn't have a use for contains, but what was interesting was seeing the different ways you can call regex that make it even faster.  I created some other methods to compare an instance use of regex and a static use with the RegexOptions.compiled.

```
public static class WordCount
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Count words with instaniated Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords4(string s)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"[\S]+");
        MatchCollection collection = r.Matches(s);
        return collection.Count;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Count words with static compiled Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords1(string s)
    {
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        return collection.Count;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Count words with static Regex.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords3(string s)
    {
        MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
        return collection.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Count word with loop and character tests.
    /// </summary>
    public static int CountWords2(string s)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i - 1]) == true)
            {
                if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]) == true ||
                    char.IsPunctuation(s[i]))
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (s.Length > 2)
        {
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

- regExCompileTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds    11787
- regExStaticTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds 12300
- regExInstanceTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds   13925
- ContainsTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds        1074

Answer (score 4):

My own bench marks appear to contradict user279470's benchmark results.

In my use case I wanted to check a simple Regex with some OR operators for 4 values versus doing 4 x `String.Contains()`.

Even with 4 x `String.Contains()`, I found that `String.Contains()` was 5 x faster.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace App.Tests.Performance
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PerformanceTesting
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();

        [TestMethod]
        public void RegexVsMultipleContains()
        {
            var matchRegex = new Regex("INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL");

            var testStrings = new List<string>();

            int iterator = 1000000 / 4; // div 4 for each of log levels checked

            for (int i = 0; i < iterator; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    var simulatedTestString = RandomString(50);

                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        simulatedTestString += "INFO";
                    }
                    else if (j == 1)
                    {
                        simulatedTestString += "WARN";
                    }
                    else if (j == 2)
                    {
                        simulatedTestString += "ERROR";
                    }
                    else if (j == 3)
                    {
                        simulatedTestString += "FATAL";
                    }

                    simulatedTestString += RandomString(50);

                    testStrings.Add(simulatedTestString);
                }
            }

            int cnt;
            Stopwatch sw;

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Multiple contains test
            //////////////////////////////////////////

            cnt = 0;
            sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < testStrings.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isMatch = testStrings[i].Contains("INFO") || testStrings[i].Contains("WARN") || testStrings[i].Contains("ERROR") || testStrings[i].Contains("FATAL");

                if (isMatch)
                {
                    cnt += 1;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("MULTIPLE CONTAINS: " + cnt + " " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Multiple contains using list test
            //////////////////////////////////////////

            cnt = 0;
            sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            var searchStringList = new List<string> { "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL" };

            for (int i = 0; i < testStrings.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isMatch = searchStringList.Any(x => testStrings[i].Contains(x));

                if (isMatch)
                {
                    cnt += 1;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("MULTIPLE CONTAINS USING LIST: " + cnt + " " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // Regex test
            ////////////////////////////////////////// 

            cnt = 0;
            sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < testStrings.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isMatch = matchRegex.IsMatch(testStrings[i]);

                if (isMatch)
                {
                    cnt += 1;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("REGEX: " + cnt + " " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for small strings Contains wins, but when I repace random string addition line with `simulatedTestString += RandomString(500);` result was almost equal, for bigger strings I believe regex will win

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for this task, string.Contains will almost certainly be faster and use less memory.  And in of course, there's no reason to use regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Regex matches are handled by .NET Framework's regular expression engine. Below is the part from the [msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) which specifies exactly when to use Regex vs String search and replacement functions:

The String class includes a number of string search and replacement methods that you can use when you want to locate literal strings in a larger string. **Regular expressions are most useful either when you want to locate one of several substrings in a larger string, or when you want to identify patterns in a string**, as the following examples illustrate.

There are two examples illustrating the same in the article.