# Is there is any performance gain when directly processing strings over RegEx?

Tags: java, regex

In Java, are there any performance gains with using string functions like `endsWith`, `startsWith`, `contains` etc., over using RegEx to accomplish same task?

Comment: define "performance gain". If by that you mean "difference when processing 10 strings per second", then **no, unless your strings are extremely long, in order of >MB**. If it means "difference when processing millions of strings per second", then **maybe/usually, depending on the exact case**.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik IFTFY *chuckles*

Comment: also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023792/regex-vs-contains-best-performance?rq=1

Comment: let's say I have a file with 2-4 millions lines, where each line 500 characters long and I have to check each line if it contains, starts with or ends with some other string value and of course I have to do as fast as possible.

Comment: I would guess that the regex will be slower because this will be interpreted. But there is only one way to be sure, do a Benchmark on 1% of your file.

Comment: @AnthonyJ. - Regex will be slower because it involves creation of instances of `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes (or atleast `Matcher`). there is some amount of synchronization going on under the hood. So, if you have a lot of Strings, using `startsWith` , `endsWith` would be better

Comment: @TheLostMind Synchronization has practically zero cost on uncontended monitors. The only perf difference can come from Java's suboptimal regex implementation, but how much is anybody's guess.

Comment: So, OP, you said you have to check each line for all three of starts with, contains, ends with. A single call to `indexOf(String)` is your best option in my opinion, unless the same string can occur at more than one place in the same line.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik sorry I think I didn't explain it correctly. I just need to use one of those function depending on some condition, so I just need to know which one is faster: string function or regex, as I always read that regex is considered expensive operation. @ TheLostMind answer was good for me

Comment: One thing is for sure: regex is not faster than a dedicated method. However there is absolutely no evidence that the dedicated method call is faster than regex. It is very likely that they perform equally well, especially given the triviality of the regex you'd use.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - But assuming that  mem barrier instruction(s) will be generated by the JVM, wouldn't *synchronization* matter? . Yes, JIT might do *lock elision* , but its not guaranteed to happen *always* right?. Yes, for uncontended monitors like `synchronized (new someObject()) {` this might have no effect, but in case of `Matcher` it can right?

Comment: @TheLostMind The only synchronization here (if any) will be on the Pattern object while it creates a new Matcher. The matcher itself is definitely a single-threaded. But if only one thread ever acquires the monitor, the thin lock will be used, which has next to zero overhead because it works like a lock that the thread acquires forever, until this is revoked by a very expensive lock inflation operation. Inflation happens at a safepoint, which is how they eliminate all cost for the happy case.

Comment: @TheLostMind I recommend Cliff Click! http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2010-01-09-biased-locking