# in java: how to know if a word exist in a long string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

would you please let me know if there is a way(java) to check is a string is exist in a long string?
**example:** check if the word hello is exist in this string "abcdffgfghdshg*hello*asdf"
in this case true sould be returned .

Best Regards,
Maya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2023792/1849366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done simply by using *contains* method

```
String orig="abcdffgfghdshghelloasdf";
if (orig.contains("hello"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: Using something like toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() might be useful as well depending of the context.

Comment: Why not just `return orig.contains("hello")`? Also note that question had `hello` is all lowercase and expected a `true` result, whereas your code returns `false` since mixedcase `Hello` is not in string.

Comment: FFS!  Please don't use the `if (exp) true else false` anti-pattern.  For one thing, it gives me a migraine.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do that in many ways, for example by using methods from **String** class:
**Contains** method - takes CharSequence as parameter:

```
boolean checkContains(){
    String orig="abcdffgfghdshghelloasdf";
    return orig.contains("hello");
}
```

**Matches** method - takes [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as parameter:

```
boolean checkMatches(){
    String orig="abcdffgfghdshghelloasdf";
    return orig.matches(".*hello.*");
}
```

Both of them are really fast, so there is no big difference which of them you will use.

Comment: They are both really fast compared to gardening, but the first method can be orders of magnitude faster than the second, and is far less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that.